# Extra batteries charger

Tags: battery

I purchased a new brand GM C Suburban. I need to install a 8 cameras and NVR security camera system, 55" monitor, and 2 laptops in this SUV. We want to design this car as a mobile security office.

I need to know if I can install another 3 extra car batteries in parallel. Will there be any negative side effects?

can somebody help me to make  3 batteries in parallel  work, as both will charge and discharge together so that I will get enough power view the camera system on 55" monitor while driving and/or when engine is set to idle.

What will it take to get this working ? Or is it even possible ?

Comment: Consider also upgrading or/and adding an additionnal alternator for charging the battery. With 3 batteries and with that kind of current draw, the stock alternator won't be able to keep up. You could even install solar panel on the roof...

Answer (score 2):

I'd point you towards my previous answer to [Adding a additional battery to car](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6116/adding-a-additional-battery-to-car/6121#6121) - You'll need to use deep-discharge leisure batteries rather than normal car batteries, and have them on a split-charge system so you don't drain the main battery while you're parked up.

All the stuff you'll need will be available off-the-shelf from a decent 4x4/RV/Marine supplier, as such systems are regularly used to power equipment in caravans and boats.